# Match and delete a string from a file

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to use `re` to search this file and delete a zone

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
zone "domain.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/domain.com.signed";
        allow-transfer { 1.2.3.4; };

 };
zone "4.3.2.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/rev.domain.com";
        allow-transfer { 1.2.3.4; };
 };

zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/example.com";
};
```

Currently I have this

```
import re

string = 'zone "example.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/zones/example.com";};'
with open('zone.conf.local') as thing:
    re.sub(r'^%s$' % string, '', thing)
```

But when I try and run this I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zone.py", line 5, in <module>
    re.sub(r'^%s$' % string, '', thing)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/hw/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I thought that maybe I shouldn't put a string the pattern for `re` but when I try this

```
import re

string = 'zone "example.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/zones/example.com";};'
with open('zone.conf.local') as thing:
    re.sub('^$', string, '', thing)
```

This still doesn't work and outputs this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zone.py", line 5, in <module>
    re.sub('^$', string, '', thing)
  File "/home/john/.virtualenvs/hw/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Use `string = r'zone\s*"example.com"\s*{\s*type\s*master;\s+file\s+"/etc/bind/zones/example.com";\s*};'` and then `new_contents = re.sub(r'(?m)^{}$'.format(string), '', thing.read())`.

Comment: So ah, what do you suspect is happening here ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works, if you want to make it a answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may declare the `string` pattern as

```
string = r'zone\s*"example.com"\s*{\s*type\s*master;\s+file\s+"/etc/bind/zones/example.com";\s*};'
```

to ensure whitespaces, `\s*` matching 0 or more whitespaces and `\s+` matching 1 or more whitespaces, and then use it like

```
new_contents = re.sub(r'(?m)^{}$'.format(string), '', thing.read())
```

Note that here, `(?m)^{}$` will anchor the `string` pattern to match the whole line: `(?m)` enables `^` to match line start rather than string start and `$` to match end of a line rather than a string end.

The `thing.read()` part will make sure you actually pass the whole file contents to the regex engine, and not a file handle.